# Why won't this where statement work?

Tags: sql

Below is the full queory, when I remove grade = "a" it works fine, why does this cause it to error out?

I get error ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier

```
select count(grade), dw_course_sect.roomID 
from dw_course_facts, dw_course_sect 
where (dw_course_facts.coursekey = dw_course_sect.coursekey) and 
      (dw_course_facts.grade = "A") 
group by dw_course_sect.roomID;
```

Comment: Might need to be in single quotes, e.g. `dw_course_facts.grade = 'A'`

Comment: Single quotes!  The simple things get me.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle (and most other databases) use double quotes as delimiters for names in SQL.  If you have a column name with a space, such as `Column Name`, then you would write `select "Column Name" . . .`.

When you write `"A"`, then Oracle is looking for a named object with that name -- a column called "A".  And there is none.

You want single quotes.  But, you should also be using standard join syntax.  The query should look like:

```
select count(grade), dw_course_sect.roomID
from dw_course_fact join
     dw_course_sect
     on dw_course_facts.coursekey = dw_course_sect.coursekey
where dw_course_facts.grade = 'A'
group by dw_course_sect.roomID;
```